# Getting Shared List (gmail address)- Google Calendar API

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am using Google Calendar API through OAuth.
So far, I would like to access events which are shared from other users.
For example, `test1@google.com` calendar is shared with `test2@google.com`

For this situation, I could access `test1@google.com` and `test2@google.com` calendar events, using access token of `test2@google.com`. I feel this is a bit dangerous in terms of security because I can see some events of `test1@google.com` without `test1@google.com`'s permission. I need just access token of `test2@google.com`.

Anyway, it is not a point. The problem is how I can get gmail address information of users who are shared, i.e. in this case, `test1@google.com` address, from `test2@google.com` information.

I came up one way to get shared list, but it is not official.
I would like to use some official API to get Shared List.

Comment: Did you try to look into the documentation? [There seems to be a](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#extendedProperties.shared) `extendedProperties.shared` property in the events resources.

Comment: Oh-, I did not imagine I can get shared information at event level. So, I did not read it deeply. But, does it help? Actually, in the above example, I actually registered some share events. But, when getting events from test2@google.com, I could not get shared events. This means that I think extendedProperties.shared does not help. But, I will try again to make sure

Comment: I tried again. I tried two patterns. One is to use "test2@google.com" as Calendar Id. And, another is to use "primary" as Calendar Id. And, I could not get events shared from "test1@google.com". So, I think extendedProperties.shared cannot be used.